# Sum of numbers from arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

The purpose of this script is to take values ​​in `int` format, display them and sum them. But my problem every time I use the command `Measure-Object` is that I just find myself displaying my figures without calculation.

```
$path = "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Projet Script\***\stat.dat_20220901_235900"
$CharArray = Get-Content -Path $path 
$CharArray = $CharArray.Split(".")
$a = $($CharArray)

$Value = "****"

foreach ($c in $a) {
    if ($c -match $Value) {
        $d = $c.Split(",")
        $e = $d[6]
        $e = $e.replace('"', '')
        [int32[]]$f = $e
        $g = ($f | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum 
        $g
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20567310
4703774
14998840
3068932
22083
672967
309701
7549299
```

The content of file is like this:

```
"1","O","I","220831 235847","E","0","219413795","az","aaaa","az","p:\logiciels\az\az\run_time\tmp\","F2461724". "1","I","R","220831 235903","E","0","87958407","PHSE","BIA_PROD2","az","p:\logiciels\axway\gateway\run_time\tmp","F2461728". "1","O","I","220831 235859","E","0","157494179","az","az","az","p:\logiciels\az\az\run_time\tmp\","F2461726". "1","O","I","220831 235905","E","0","87958407","PHSE","az","**","p:\logiciels\az\az\run_time\tmp\","F2461728"
```

Comment: What does the content of stat.dat look like? You are currently summing up something, but only one per line of the file. To sum them all, capture the output from foreach: `$LineValues = foreach ($c in $a) {...}`, then sum that `$LineValues | Measure -Sum`

Comment: the content of file is like this :"1","O","I","220831 235847","E","0","219413795","az","aaaa","az","p:\logiciels\az\az\run_time\tmp\","F2461724".
"1","I","R","220831 235903","E","0","87958407","PHSE","BIA_PROD2","az","p:\logiciels\axway\gateway\run_time\tmp","F2461728".
"1","O","I","220831 235859","E","0","157494179","az","az","az","p:\logiciels\az\az\run_time\tmp\","F2461726".
"1","O","I","220831 235905","E","0","87958407","PHSE","az","**","p:\logiciels\az\az\run_time\tmp\","F2461728".

Comment: version-specific tags are only for bugs/issues that *only* occur/apply to that specific version. Don't use them for general issues. And do not post information in comments. [edit] the question and put the updated contents in proper format

Comment: @oussama_tr I pasted the file contents into your post, but it's unclear whether it also contains line breaks or not. Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74491574/edit) if it's not correct

Comment: @oussama_tr What is `$value` supposed to be? `****` is not valid for `-match`.  If all you want is to sum your current output, the first comment should still be correct

Comment: is ok @Cpt.Whale, i find the solution because of your help. the result is an array of int and  i should search by variable to use Measure -sum, so i added in the end foreach($g in $f){$g},   thanks a lot for your help

Comment: fwiw I've never been able to get the measure-object command to work for avg and sum.  And I've tried with [int[]] arrays in multiple versions.  It's just borked imho.  Wish they'd ported over the sum method on lists from c#.